# How to alter loop behavior for index 3, 5 and 15?

Tags: php, for-loop

I don't want to display the numbers 3, 5 and 15. I want you to show when my program runs

> 1 2 three 4 five 6 7 ...

```
$var1 = 3;
$var2 = 5;
$var3 = 15;

for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {

  if($i<=3){
    if (($i%$var1)==0) 
      echo 'Three' .'<br/>';
  } 

  if($i<=5)
    if (($i%$var2)==0) {
      echo 'Five' .'<br/>';
    }

  if($i<=15) 
    if ((($i%$var3)==0)) {
      echo 'ThreeFive' .'<br/>';
    }

  echo $i.'<br/>';  
}
```

Comment: What do you need this for? It seems there may be a better general solution.

Comment: u have to use continue keyword for that

Comment: ♥ FizzBuzz.  Pity someone had to go and make it dull.

Answer (score 3):

A rather crude, but working solution would be this:

```
$var1 = 3;
$var2 = 5;
$var3 = 15;

for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ) {
  switch( $i ) {
    case $var1: echo 'Three<br>'; break;
    case $var2: echo 'Five<br>'; break;
    case $var3: echo 'ThreeFive<br>'; break;
    default:    echo $i.'<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check with this code

```
$exclude_array = array(3,5,15);
for($i = 0;$i < 100; $i++){
   if(!in_array($i,$exclude_array))
   echo $i;
}
```

Comment: ...`else echo $exclude_array[$i]`?

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more elegant solution...

```
$alter = array(3=>"Three<br>", 5=>"Five<br>", 15=>"ThreeFive<br>");
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++) echo isset($alter[$i]) ? $alter[$i] : $i;
```

I suppose you wanted to print *Three* and *Five* every time the `$i` is divisible by 3 or 5. Then you may alter it this way:

```
$alter = array(3=>"Three", 5=>"Five");
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
    $print_word = false;
    foreach($alter as $key=>$val) if($i>0 && $i%$key==0) {
        echo $val;
        $print_word = true;
    }
    echo $print_word ? "<br>" : $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
    $var1 = 3;
             $var2 = 5;
             $var3 = 15;

              for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {

             if ($i==$var1) 
            echo 'Three' .'<br/>';


            else if ($i==$var2) {
            echo 'Five' .'<br/>';
           }

            else if ($i==$var3) {
            echo 'ThreeFive' .'<br/>';
           }
else
            echo $i.'<br/>';  
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :)

```
   <?php

    $var1 = 3;
    $var2 = 5;
    $var3 = 15;

    for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
        if($i == $var1){
            echo "three <br />";
        }elseif($i == $var2){
            echo "five <br />";
        }elseif($i == $var3){
            echo "Fifteen <br />";
        }else{
            echo $i."<br />";
        }
    }

?>
```